# ClassLoader used by tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, intellij-idea

I got this class not found error. The class name is com.bandstand.web.StartupListener in a webapp.
I click on the class WebappClassLoader in the stack trace (below) it lead me to
gwt-2.5.0\gwt-dev.jar!\org\apache\catalina\loader\WebappClassLoader

This is weird because I don't use any gwt class in this webapp (artifact) although I used it in another artifact.

Does IntelliJ just falsely map the class name? (WebappClassLoader)

If you are experienced with tomcat, can you confirm the loading chain as normal? Bootstrap->Method.invoke->... (without gwt, it still loads that way)

Thanks heaps

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.bandstand.web.StartupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bandstand.web.StartupListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is this bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63362. It should be fixed in [IDEA 12.1 RC build](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP).